# Openshift load balancing doesn't work well

Tags: node.js, openshift, load-balancing

I have a node express server that I am deploying on openshift. The server accepts http requests that usually take 30 seconds to complete. I have 5 pods that run that application however all of the requests are usually handled by 2-3 pods with one of them usually handling about 75 percent of them. I tried to use the openshift tools for load balancing. Here is what I added to the router yaml:

```
haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance : roundrobin
haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies : 'true'
```

I also tried the leastconn option but didn't see any impact.

Comment: "*I tried to use the openshift tools for load balancing*" What do you mean by that? "*Here is what I added to the router yaml*", do you mean you add those as annotations to your route?

Comment: yes, I added the annotations to the route but didn't see a change